# Log4j2 File Inclusion : <include> and <included> similar to Logback

Tags: java, logging, configuration, log4j, log4j2

Does Log4j2 support file inclusion mechanism like Logback does ? This is for including parts of a configuration file from another file (containing appenders, loggers etc.)

As an FYI - Here is how it works in Logback:

Joran supports including parts of a configuration file from another file. This is done by declaring a  element, as shown below:

Example: File include (logback-examples/src/main/java/chapters/configuration/containingConfig.xml)

```
<configuration>
<include file="src/main/java/chapters/configuration/includedConfig.xml"/>

<root level="DEBUG">
<appender-ref ref="includedConsole" />
</root>
```

The target file MUST have its elements nested inside an  element. For example, a ConsoleAppender could be declared as:

Example: File include (logback-examples/src/main/java/chapters/configuration/includedConfig.xml)

```
<included>
<appender name="includedConsole" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
<encoder>
  <pattern>"%d - %m%n"</pattern>
</encoder>
</appender>
</included>
```

Answer (score 6):

XInclude can be used, but isn't an ideal solution.  When using XInclude the include files themselves have to define a single top level element such as Appenders/Loggers/Properties.

Here's an example of how you could use it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="error" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
    <!-- this will override the log pattern defined in the included log4j-properties.xml -->
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-pattern">jit %d %-5p [%t] %C{1.} - %m%n</Property>
    </Properties>

    <xi:include href="log4j2-properties.xml" />
    <xi:include href="log4j2-appenders.xml" />
    <xi:include href="log4j2-loggers.xml" />
</Configuration>
```

As an example include the log4j2-properties.xml could look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Properties>
    <!-- define the log pattern as a property so that it can be overridden -->
    <Property name="log-pattern">%d %-5p [%t] %C{1.} - %m%n</Property>
</Properties>
```

You can make XIncludes optional by using an empty "fallback" block.  However in the latest version of log4j2 that is available this results in a warning message coming out of Xerces (since the DefaultErrorHandler is being used by log4j2).

```
<xi:include href="log4j2-optional.xml">
    <xi:fallback />
</xi:include>
```

Answer (score 4):

A slightly different but similar mechanism exists in Log4j2, it supports XInclude.
See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-341 for details. (This needs to be documented better...)

**Edit**: the docs are here:
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XInclude

Comment: I tried this approach - <xi:include href="sample.xml"/>. However, the problem with XInclude is the referenced file becomes mandatory always. When developing framework components around logging, there would also be cases where is no requirement to include seperate log configuration. The logback's approach have the optional attribute which ignores if the file is not present. for e.g. <include resource="sample.xml" optional="true" />

Comment: You may want to raise this as a feature request on the Log4j2 Jira issue tracker.

Comment: Or is this what you are looking for? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-494

Comment: Thanks for that pointer. Yeah, kind of, but more important is that the additional configuration be treated as optional. ie. if the additional configuration is not present, then allow log4j2 to continue with the default configuration.

Comment: This feature is so important to us, that it might prevent us to move from logback to log4j2 until it's available. What's the possibility of including this feature in the next upcoming release ? I can open a feature request or update any existing ticket if that's preferred.

Comment: If LOG4J2-494 is not exactly what you need, I'd open a new ticket and mention how your request differs from LOG4J2-494 (to prevent it from being marked a duplicate). If you really want this feature as soon as possible please consider also submitting a patch.