# How to correctly use log4j2 in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, log4j2, slf4j

I wanted to include log4j2 for the logging purpose in my application only.
So I included the following dependency in  the pom.xml of my project:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

But at the start of the application I get the following exceptions :

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/m2repo/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/m2repo/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.12.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.12.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

On researching more about it on many platforms I found an approach to exclude logback dependency as I thought I need to 
use the log4j2.But after excluding that jar also I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: org.apache.logging.log4j.LoggingException: log4j-slf4j-impl cannot be present with log4j-to-slf4j
```

So for solving that:
I excluded the log4j-to-slf4j dependency also.

And finally it starts working but now I see a ton of log messages which are more related to Spring boot Internal.
For instance :

```
2019-12-05 12:05:01.649 [DEBUG]  [restartedMain] - Included patterns for restart : []
2019-12-05 12:05:01.649 [DEBUG]  [restartedMain] - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter/target/classes/]
2019-12-05 12:05:01.649 [INFO ]  [restartedMain] - Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2019-12-05 12:05:01.649 [DEBUG]  [restartedMain] - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3883fd6d
2019-12-05 12:05:01.666 [DEBUG]  [restartedMain] - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
2019-12-05 12:05:01.686 [DEBUG]  [restartedMain] - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory'
2019-12-05 12:05:02.037 [DEBUG]  [restartedMain] - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer'
2019-12-05 12:05:02.043 [DEBUG]  [restartedMain] - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator'
2019-12-05 12:05:02.055 [DEBUG]  [restartedMain] - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
2019-12-05 12:05:02.056 [DEBUG]  [restartedMain] - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
2019-12-05 12:05:02.059 [DEBUG]  [restartedMain] - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
```

My pom.xml is like :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.log4j2</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j2-check</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>log4j2-check</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

also log4j2 properties like :

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = Test
appenders = console
appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%-5level]  [%t] - %msg%n
rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = STDOUT
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

How can or what are correct configurations needed to use log4j2 only for application purposes and not for Spring boot.

Comment: If you only want to log your application at debug then set the root logger level to warn and then add a logger for the package space that your application uses and set that to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I identified the issue which triggered the printing of unexpected messages from spring boot.
From the log4j2 configuration I had set the following

`rootLogger.level = debug`

This property makes the log4j2 to print all the internal messages of spring boot set to debug mode also to print.

Changing it to following :

`rootLogger.level = info`

solves the issue.

Now the application prints only those loggers whose level is greater than **info**.
So now, it does not print unwanted log messages.

I would say it was not an issue, log4j2 was working correct but my configuration settings were not correct as per my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because log4j2 loggers handling spring boot internal files are included into your configuration.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/logging/log4j2/log4j2.xml) - this are relevant definitions.

Technically I'm not really familiar with log2j2 but it seems that it supports [xInclude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694782/log4j2-file-inclusion-include-and-included-similar-to-logback) directive